# LDAP query using Python: always no result

Tags: python, django, apache, ldap

I am trying to use python to query LDAP server, and it always returns me no result. and anyone help me find what wrong with my python code? it runs fine without excpetions, and it always has no result. i played around with the filter like "cn=*partofmyname*" but just no luck.
thanks for help

```
import ldap



try:
    l = ldap.open("server")
    l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
    l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
    output =l.simple_bind("cn=username,cn=Users,dc=domian, dc=net",'password$R')
    print output
except ldap.LDAPError, e:
    print e

baseDN = "DC=domain,DC=net"
searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
## retrieve all attributes - again adjust to your needs - see documentation for more options
retrieveAttributes = None

Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=myaccount))"

try:
    ldap_result_id = l.search(baseDN, searchScope, Filter, retrieveAttributes)
    print ldap_result_id
    result_set = []
    while 1:
        result_type, result_data = l.result(ldap_result_id, 0)
        if len(result_data) == 0:
            print 'no reslut'
            break
        else:
            for i in range(len(result_set)):
                for entry in result_set[i]:
                    try:
                        name = entry[1]['cn'][0]
                        email = entry[1]['mail'][0]
                        phone = entry[1]['telephonenumber'][0]
                        desc = entry[1]['description'][0]
                        count = count + 1
                        print "%d.\nName: %s\nDescription: %s\nE-mail: %s\nPhone: %s\n" %\
                              (count, name, desc, email, phone)
                    except:
                        pass
                        ## here you don't have to append to a list
                        ## you could do whatever you want with the individual entry
            #if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
             # result_set.append(result_data)
            #  print result_set
except ldap.LDAPError, e:
    print e
l.unbind()
```

Comment: I don't know - for some reason I preferred the 'ReSlut' title before edits http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3057039/revisions It made me look.

Comment: The python `ldap` module also has an option to turn on / increase verbosity of debugging messages routed to std output if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found my problem.

```
simple_bind("cn=username,cn=Users,dc=domian, dc=net",'password$R')
```

should be

```
   simple_bind("domain/username",'password$R')
```

Comment: dunno if it matters, but in the first line *domain* is mispelt, should be `dc=domain` (the idea being maybe both syntaxes work).

Comment: This only works in Active Directory. The previous version should work in all LDAP directories. If you need compatibility, don't use this option.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend that you examine the network traffic using Wireshark (www.wireshark.org) to see what's happening at the protocol level.  Also, get a tool such as Softerra LDAP browser 2.6 (the free version at http://www.ldapbrowser.com/download.htm) to check the A/D server and directory organization.

If you still have problems, post a summary of what you find using these tools.